# How can i decode the text contains &amp;amp; using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to decode the values after &amp, & is converted to & value. But amp is not converting.

```
 string MyString = "some text &amp;amp";
 Console.WriteLine(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(MyString));
```

`So my result is "some text &amp"`

But i want to remove the another amp also. In Html decode it is not happening. Please give me better solution

Comment: Why should it decode? Just "amp" isn't encoded.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Why it is coming two amp; amp i don't know. how to handle this?

Comment: `&amp` is not valid encoded, thous can't be decoded. A valid value to decode would be `&amp;` (with semicolon at the end). And if it would be valid you could simply put the resulting string from the first decode another time into the decode method.

Comment: If your string contains a ; at the end also (not shown here) then presumably someone encoded it twice. You then could decode twice but the actual problem is in encoding.

Comment: @UdhayamaniVellaichamy `&amp;` translates to `&` that explains `&` + `amp` = `&amp`

Comment: "some text & " This is my result should be. Second amp i need to remove it?

Comment: Use `string MyString = "some text &amp;"`. Unless your string isn't actually hard-coded? Where is that string coming from? It's probably wrong there; you need to prevent whatever's sending it from sending the wrong text.

Answer (score -1):

Your example text is invalid to be decoded twice. A correct text would look like

```
some text &amp;amp;
```

With this text you could just take two rounds for decoding:

```
var someText = "some text &amp;amp;";
var firstRound = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(someText);
Console.WriteLine(firstRound);

var secondRound = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(firstRound);
Console.WriteLine(secondRound);
```

If you don't know how many rounds to take, you could try decoding, till the text doesn't change anymore:

```
var someText = "some text &amp;amp;";

string currentResult;
string lastResult = someText;
do
{
    currentResult = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(lastResult);

    if(currentResult != lastResult)
    {
        lastResult = currentResult;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```